# Setting Custom Suggestions for SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I have a `SearchView` in my ActionBar with this code that suggests Applications to launch as you type. I use this code:

```
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchManager != null) {
        List<SearchableInfo> searchables = searchManager
                .getSearchablesInGlobalSearch();

        // Try to use the "applications" global search provider
        SearchableInfo info = searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        for (SearchableInfo inf : searchables) {
            if (inf.getSuggestAuthority() != null
                    && inf.getSuggestAuthority().startsWith("applications")) {
                info = inf;
            }
        }
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

But what I need is for the SearchView to simply suggest Strings that I provide through an ArrayList. And instead of launching an application on SearchView submit, I want to simply call a method with the String. Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `MatrixCursor`, custom `CursorAdapter` and a custom view for displaying suggestions. More info is [here](http://tpbapp.com/android-development/android-action-bar-searchview-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you dealt with Adapters before? Like for ListViews? Just create an adapter with your list of strings and set it as the suggestions adapter on the SearchView.

```
searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It takes a CursorAdapter, so I can't use something simple like an ArrayAdapter

Comment: @Harry yes you can,  see MatrixCursor